# Comma delimited record in a table (Split/Merge) on SQL server 2005

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table with comma separated column like below

```
__table 1__  
_ID Value_  
1    2,3,5  
2    1,3  
3    1,2,3,4
```

I also have another description table

```
__table 2__   
_Value Description_  
1       Banana  
2       Orange  
3       Apple  
4       Mango  
5       Strawberry
```

I want to join both tables and want to have the following output

```
_ID   Value    Description_    
1    2,3,5    Orange,Apple,Strawberry  
2    1,3      Banana,Apple  
3    1,2,3,4  Banana,Orange,Apple,Mango
```

Please help me to make T-SQL query or function or stored procedure for SQL SERVER 2005 to have the above output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I worked on it too, I don't think it performs awesomely, but here is my solution :

```
SELECT
    t.ID
    ,t.Value
    ,STUFF((
        SELECT ',' + t2.Description
        FROM 
            table1 as t1
            inner join table2 as t2
                on (',' + LTRIM(RTRIM(t1.Value)) + ',') LIKE '%,' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),t2.Value) + ',%'
        WHERE t1.ID = t.ID
        ORDER BY t2.Description --Can be removed
        FOR XML PATH('')
    ), 1, 1, '') as description
FROM 
    table1 as t
```

The subquery will join values from table 1 with the value of table 2 and retrieve descriptions. Then use `FOR XML PATH` and `STUFF` to concatenate the multiple rows description into a single row.

You can see the [SQLFiddle Demo here](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/7d790/16)

Comment: Nice solution. I was thinking about using cursor and create some function. But your way is better

Comment: @Fnightangel thank you. Yes, I thought about that SPLIT function too, but I wanted to try that kind of join. Talking about cursor, cursor is something you should never ever ever use ! Because you know it's a performance killer. Sometimes you have no choice but you have so many tricks to do what you want :)

Comment: @user3576398 Glad it helps. Make sure you get the status of the answer to resolved.

Answer (score 0):

If I may say, this design is flawed. But then again, it presents a nice problem to solve :)

First we had to split the list of values into a tabular shape, use this to get the descriptions, and then concatenate the descriptions in the same order as values were ordered.

Here's the solution:

```
;with a as (
    select #t1.id, #t1.value, #t2.description, x.n
    from #t1
    cross apply (
        select substring(value, n, charindex(',', value + ',', n) - n), n
        from numbers 
        where substring(',' + value, n, 1) = ','
        and n < len(value) + 1
    ) x (a, n)
    inner join #t2 on x.a = #t2.value
)
select distinct a1.id, a1.value, substring(c, 1, len(c)-1)
from a a1
cross apply (
    select a2.description + ', ' as [text()]
    from a a2
    where a1.id = a2.id
    order by n
    for xml path('')
) y (c)
```

As you can see, you will need a [numbers table](http://dataeducation.com/you-require-a-numbers-table/) to run this. But you need numbers table anyway.